# Extracting Lat/Long from returned json via google api(Geocoding)

Tags: python, json, google-maps-api-3

I have a definition which looks like the below block. I think I'm experiencing the same problem. I think the api has updated, and thus the extraction of the lat/long coordinates may be in a slightly different position. I have made requests successfully by inputing an example address in as a parameter, but I can't get that to work in my def(http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#make-a-request). I want my definition to return the lat/longs from the address using a for loop. I'm unfamiliar with parsing json:/ Any help appreciated!

Also, would `geocode_result` need to be `json_results` from my request results codeblock?

```
 def geocode_address(loc):
        gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key= creds.GOOGLE_MAPS['api_key'])
        geocode_result = gmaps.geocode(loc)
        lat = json_results[0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"]
        lon = json_results[0]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"]
        print (lat,lon)
```

[image: wanted lat/long from this position for a list of addresses I pass in in my definition]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a difference between what this does and what your code does. Hope it's of some use to you.

```
>>> import requests
>>> payload = {'key':}
>>> base_url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json'
>>> payload = {'address': '1845 E. Broadway Road Ste. 102, Tempe, AE, 85282'}
>>> r = requests.get(base_url, params=payload)
>>> r
<Response [200]>
>>> coords = r.json()['results'][0]['geometry']['location']
>>> coords['lat']
33.406601
>>> coords['lng']
-111.9075196
```

**EDIT**:

Start with a dataframe of two columns, one with the names of the veterinary hospitals, one with their addresses.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df
                            0  \
0           The Animal Clinic   
1  Sherbourne Animal Hospital   
2     Spadina Animal Hospital   
3   Wellesley Animal Hospital   
4      Cabbagetown Pet Clinic   

                                                   1  
0            106 Mutual St  Toronto  Ontario M5B 2R7  
1  320 Richmond Street East Unit 8  Toronto  Onta...  
2       125 Spadina Avenue  Toronto  Ontario M5V 2K8  
3         8 Wellesley St W  Toronto  Ontario M4Y 1E7  
4         239 Gerrard St E  Toronto  Ontario M5A 2G1
```

Use `.tolist()` to obtain the addresses in the form of a list so that they can be passed one at a time to google for their latitudes and longitudes which are stored in the eponymous lists. Display the results.

```
>>> import requests
>>> base_url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json'
>>> latitudes = []
>>> longitudes = []
>>> for address in df[1].tolist():
...     payload = {'address': address}
...     r = requests.get(base_url, params=payload)
...     coords = r.json()['results'][0]['geometry']['location']
...     latitudes.append(coords['lat'])
...     longitudes.append(coords['lng'])
...     
>>> latitudes
[43.6572571, 43.6535161, 43.6472168, 43.6650199, 43.6617416]
>>> longitudes
[-79.37609119999999, -79.3688681, -79.39527749999999, -79.3851912, -79.369494]
```

Now put the results into the dataframe and display the complete result.

```
>>> df['latitudes'] = latitudes
>>> df['longitudes'] = longitudes
>>> df
                            0  \
0           The Animal Clinic   
1  Sherbourne Animal Hospital   
2     Spadina Animal Hospital   
3   Wellesley Animal Hospital   
4      Cabbagetown Pet Clinic   

                                                   1  lat  latitudes  \
0            106 Mutual St  Toronto  Ontario M5B 2R7  -31  43.657257   
1  320 Richmond Street East Unit 8  Toronto  Onta...  -42  43.653516   
2       125 Spadina Avenue  Toronto  Ontario M5V 2K8  -20  43.647217   
3         8 Wellesley St W  Toronto  Ontario M4Y 1E7   19  43.665020   
4         239 Gerrard St E  Toronto  Ontario M5A 2G1   50  43.661742   

   longitudes  
0  -79.376091  
1  -79.368868  
2  -79.395277  
3  -79.385191  
4  -79.369494
```

Comment: Thanks! You're totally right @Bill Bell. I was seeing the mapping of names to the outputs. Do you happen to know why my basic for loop will not print the (lat,lng), but it does if I just do `location['lat'], location['lng']? I have added pics of my list of strings, and the desired output without the for loop.

Comment: How do you define `api_list`?

Comment: The api_list is the second photo. It's a dataframes column that I converted to a list that I want to pass into the loop. The issue is that payload is hard coded for that single address so I need my dictionairy to keep the single key, but have unique addresses for each key value pair(this would come from the api_list. I attempted something like this:
```payload = {}
keys = api_key
api_list
for i in keys:
    payload[i] = api_list[i]```

Comment: Up until now I've been able to use your screen captures. Now the bad news. Normally here on SO we ask for code in text form rather than screen captures so that we can try code out more readily. Would it be possible for you to post another question where you focus on this problem and post your code as text, please? I think I need to be able to follow how you get `api_list` exactly.

Comment: Definitely. Sorry for the confusion. I will post a bit later.

Comment: No worries! If you drop me a comment here I'll look for it.

Comment: `address_merge_df = pd.DataFrame(VCH_hospitals_one.address_1) ### convert each column to DATAframe so can merge
address_merge_df
city_state_zip_df = pd.DataFrame(VCH_hospitals_one.city_state_zip)
lat_long_list = pd.concat([address_merge_df, city_state_zip_df], axis = 1)
def get_api_address(row):
    return row['address_1'] + ', '+ row['city_state_zip']
    
lat_long_list['api_address'] = lat_long_list.apply(get_api_address, axis = 1) 

api_list = lat_long_list.api_address.tolist() ### had to convert to list for geocode to recognize format(zip ok)
api_list`

Comment: The above retrieved the `api_list`,which is just a concatenated address from my dataframe that I want geo coded such as `15990 S. Rancho Sahuarita Blvd., Sahuarita, AZ, 85629''  In the first part you helped with I had hard coded an address in the dictionary `payload` which is what I need to populate with `api_list`, but keep the same api_key for each unique address I believe. Let me know if that helps. If not..we can avoid further confusion. Thanks for the helps!

Comment: Becoming confused. You have a column of addresses (veterinary care hospitals?) in a dataframe to which you want to add a column of latitudes and longitudes?

Comment: Hey @Bill Bell. Yup, that's exactly correct. If it's too much trouble, no worries at all. Just learning:)

Comment: thanks for much for this as it helps a lot! I appreciate the time. This is awesome. Keep up the good work!